# Converting a String to Collapse Multiple Instances of Letters into a Letter and Numeral Representation of it

Tags: c#, string, replace

For example if I were to have

```
   Textbox1.Text = "aaaabbbccDdff";
```

How would I convert that to a letter and numeral representation of the letters based on how many of them are in a row, ie having it turn into

```
  Textbox2.Text = "a4b3c2Ddf2";
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? This looks be be a trivial problem. Consider the rules of the operation. 1. Count the number of identical letters in a row. 2. Append results to string in the format `{letter}{count}`. 3. Repeat.

Comment: Not another 'Please do my work for me' post

Comment: @ColinSteel Ye, sounds like homework.

Comment: Not homework.I need to learn replace string format.

Comment: @MehmetAkyel You need to post your effort also, What effort you put in before posting your question.Posting a question should be the last thing you do.

Comment: @SurajSingh you are right.Sorry

Comment: @MehmetAkyel Well i never intended it to make you sorry you don't even need to be, It was just a info and BTW i do not appreciate rude comments above by some users and `-ve` votes  there is always a way to say things in some other way which can actually bring results .Good luck !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
string s = Textbox1.Text; //"aaaabbbccfffff";
string r = "";
int count = 0;
char currChar = s[0];
for(int i = 0; i < s.Length + 1; i++)
{
    if(i >= s.Length || currChar != s[i])
    {
        r += currChar + count.ToString();
        count = 1;
        if(i < s.Length)
            currChar = s[i];
    }
    else count++;
}

Textbox2.Text = r;
```

For the Linq fanatics:

```
var r = string.Join("", s.GroupBy(c=>c).Select(x=>x.Key+x.Count().ToString()));
```

Comment: @MehmetAkyel I added a more fashion version using Linq